# Python version specification in pycharm terminal

Tags: python-3.x, terminal, pycharm

In pycharm's built in terminal how can I specify which version of python I want to run? With my standard terminal I can type either 'python' or 'python3' to run 2.7 or 3.5 respectively however when I try this in the pycharm terminal I can still run 2.7 with the 'python' prompt, but the python3 prompt results in a "command not found" error. I'm really new to python, command lines and programming in general so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Pycharm > Settings > Project Interpreter

Comment: this does nothing for the terminal. This only sets the project to use python3 not the terminal